# Preventing content visibility underneath a transparent fixed navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a semi-transparent navigation bar that has a fixed position at the top of the window, and content underneath it.

I'd like to make it so that the `#content` isn't **ever** visible underneath the navigation bar. Setting the top margin of the content to the same height as the navigation bar works, when the user is at the top of the page. However when the user scrolls down, the content becomes visible underneath the navigation bar.

Basically I'm trying to push/clip the top of the content div, so none of its content is ever visible underneath the navigation bar.

The navigation bar's transparency is particularly important, so simply having an opaque gray background won't work for what I need.

Any suggestions for accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

### Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAMka/

HTML:

```
<nav id="top">
    <div style="margin: 12px;">foo</div>
</nav>

<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#content {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

JS:

```
// This is a little cleaner than just manually repeating the p tags.
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    $('#content').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis dolor in sem tempus rutrum. Nullam mattis sodales mi, eu bibendum ante porta quis. Phasellus dui sem, imperdiet at massa in, imperdiet vestibulum leo.</p>');
}
```

### Some mock-ups of what I'm trying to do

This is what the fiddle will look like if you scroll down a little bit. Notice how the content is visible underneath the navigation bar.
[image]

Ideally, I'd like the content to be clipped, so it isn't visible underneath the navigation bar.
[image]

### Update:

Although not ideal, I figured out a somewhat hackish way to achieve what I want involving some JS and the `overflow:hidden` CSS setting. It seems to work well enough for my purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/NAMka/4/

HTML:

```
<nav id="top">
    <div style="margin: 12px;">foo</div>
</nav>

<div id="container">
    <div id="veil">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#container {
    background: yellow;    
    margin-top: 60px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}

#veil {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

#content {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;    
}
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('#content').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis dolor in sem tempus rutrum. Nullam mattis sodales mi, eu bibendum ante porta quis. Phasellus dui sem, imperdiet at massa in, imperdiet vestibulum leo.</p>');
}

var height = $('#content').height();
$('#container').height(height);
$('#veil').height(height);

$(window).scroll(function() {    

    $('#veil').height($('#content').height() - $(window).scrollTop() );  

});
```

Comment: what do want visible through the navigation bar?

Comment: Anything and everything except the contents of the `#content` div.

Comment: Because there will be other things underneath the the navigation bar that I'd like the user to be able to see (though there's nothing in this example).

Comment: @rectangletangle The solution in your update is fantastic. However, you might want to submit it as an answer so the question is marked as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a white div that sits beneath the navbar but above the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/naLz7/

HTML

```
<nav id="top">
    <div style="margin: 12px;">foo</div>
</nav>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
}

#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```